# Screen capture of Winforms control instance that is not on a Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, capture

Is there a way to obtain a bitmap rendering of a Windows Forms control, specifically a WebBrowser, upon creating an instance, but not adding it to a visible form? A mechanism like WPF's measure & arrange that would allow me to render it to a bitmap.

I'm targetting .NET 4.0 and looking for a way to capture the WebBrowser control's contents without ever displaying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question: [WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap() or other methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434156/webbrowser-drawtobitmap-or-other-methods)

Comment: The DrawToBitmap doesn't perform very well with websites that contain flash (captures only the section down to the flash movie) and the native GDI+ method only works with visible, displayed components.

Comment: I managed to use DrawToBitmap after all, as long as I don't click the control, it manages to capture the image fine.