# local html with javascript file to image

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have local file that contain some html with javascript and i want to capture it and save it as an image.

i tried to do it with WebBrowser:

```
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.Navigate("C:\\charts\\pie.html");
            HtmlDocument doc = browser.Document;
            Bitmap bitmap = GenerateScreenshot(browser);
            bitmap.Save("c:\\charts\\sample.png");


        public static Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(WebBrowser wb)
        {
            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
            wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
            wb.Dispose();

            return bitmap;
        }
```

but i get every time blank image...

any idea??

Comment: On moment of returning bitmap is it null or not?

Comment: its nut null. but maybe its empty. how can i know?

Answer (score 0):

`DrawToBitmap` has limitations and dont always work as expected. Try instead work with native GDI+

As Cory already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434156/webbrowser-drawtobitmap-or-other-methods/2434231#2434231)

Refer another example [here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Generate-WebPage-Thumbmail-Screenshot-Image)