# Screen Shot From Flash Player Content

Tags: c#, flash, screenshot

I'm trying to take screen shots from a simple web browser I created using C#.
here's what I've found so far

```
public class NativeMethods
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("0000010D-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IViewObject
    {
        void Draw([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwAspect, int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, [In] IntPtr ptd, IntPtr hdcTargetDev, IntPtr hdcDraw, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref RECT lprcBounds, [In] IntPtr lprcWBounds, IntPtr pfnContinue, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwContinue);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    public static void GetImage(object obj, Image destination, Color backgroundColor)
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destination))
        {
            IntPtr deviceContextHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            RECT rectangle = new RECT();

            rectangle.Right = destination.Width;
            rectangle.Bottom = destination.Height;

            graphics.Clear(backgroundColor);

            try
            {
                deviceContextHandle = graphics.GetHdc();

                IViewObject viewObject = obj as IViewObject;
                viewObject.Draw(1, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, deviceContextHandle, ref rectangle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (deviceContextHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    graphics.ReleaseHdc(deviceContextHandle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well, this perfectly works if it's a normal web page, but when the flash player loads the content, I get blank black images. What I want to do is to be able to take screen shots from the flash content even if the browser is minimised programmatically of course.

So Is there a way to modify this code somehow? or a way to access the the flash player's cache and export images out of it?

Answer (score 1):

found another method to take screen shots and it's robust enough to be working while a flash content is displayed.

[Screen shot from any control in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434156/webbrowser-drawtobitmap-or-other-methods/27590132#27590132)